# Sidebar disappeared on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

For some reason the sidebar and the top bar disappeared on my Ubuntu 14.04. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> does not start a terminal. I tried to remove `.config` and `.cache/compizconfig-1`, I tried to restart and reinstall unity, but to no avail.

I have some files on my desktop. If I open them, the corresponding application starts but the menu at the top does not show.

I also tried to use ccsm as suggested here [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) but it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open a tty terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Next, log into your account and run the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
sudo rm -rf ~/.compiz
sudo rm -rf ~/.Xauthority
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! `sudo rm -rf ~/.Xauthority` was the only thing I had not tried.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to delete folders in home directory?

Comment: I can't seem to be able to type the sign ~  Everytime I try, I only get "   I use international type o keyboard, so I don't know what's the cause of this. Anyway, now I can't fix my Unity problem due to a missing ~ !!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to open *Settings → Dock → Position on Screen* and choose one of them. The icons will reappear.

Comment: I don't understand where is Dock in settings application. P.S.  I found it, another settings category was selected.  You need to go back to all settings, becase it shows last settings you have used not all category settings from scratch.