# 3/23/20 glib security update Ubuntu 16.04 broke Unity Search - Desktop Icons, Top/Side taskbars disappear

Tags: unity, icons, search

After installing Glib security update on 3/23/20, clicking on Unity search causes the desktop icons and top and side task bars to blink/disappear several times. After which desktop and task bars return. Can select icons on side and top bar and run programs. So everything is normal, except Unity search.

Have tried several fixes that have worked prior when updates broke Unity search. Some listed below (with personal notes included):

---

USE THIS - WORKED - 07/01/2019 - MAYBE NOT LOST SHORTCUTS, BACKGROUND 11/15/18 - shutdown, restart - click unity search, several times, seems to correct itself.

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Then SHUTDOWN
Then Start

** This worked after using above. Try first, then go thru above if not work.
CHANGE: 03/17/20 Do above first. Worked!! Below may be deprecated.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo reboot
```

At this point it is no go with above fixes.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

---

UPDATE: SUCCESS! Thank you! Just a note on 4th command:

user@user:~$ sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
[sudo] password for user: 
error: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=be77589467904c6abc1de45628646cdc --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1

Usage:
  dconf reset [-f] PATH

Reset a key or dir.  -f is required for dirs.

Arguments:
  PATH        Either a KEY or DIR
  KEY         A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
  DIR         A directory path (starting and ending with '/')

---

The file "be77589467904c6abc1de45628646cdc" I believe is deprecated or is the new one that doesn't play well with 16.04. I'm not sure which one the aforementioned file is. But, regardless of error, the first three commands and the fifth did the trick! You have my sincere gratitude!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, mine unity search (16.04LTS) works without problems. I noticed the paulo-miguel-dias ppa is for 18.04+, adding repository into 16.04 might not hep.

Answer (score 0):

Citation from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943959/sidebar-disappeared-on-ubuntu-14-04) and other websites tell us that the method might bring back the Unity dash and side panel.

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
rm -rf ~/.compiz
rm -rf ~/.Xauthority
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
poweroff --reboot
```

I suggest the Unity Tweak Tool for editing items up to you.

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

[image: Unity Tweak Tool]

Other restorations of the Unity panels and functions are described link below.

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: Have Unity Tweak Tool. Couldn't get to due to aforementioned problem. Which was, Clicking on Unity "Search Your Computer" icon caused desktop and task bars to blink/flash for several times, then return to normal. But no ability to search and then access search results. i.e. Tweak tool